# Truncate sorted list of list based on value

Tags: python

I have a list of list pairs such as `[['0.0', 'AAA'], ['0.0', 'AAC'], ['0.2', 'BBB']]` I want to truncate the list based on the value of the first position. So in this example, I want to retain only `[['0.0', 'AAA'], ['0.0', 'AAC']]` because both values are zero.

I was trying to do it as a list comprehension along the lines of `[s,c if s == min_score for s,c in this_amino]` where `this_amino` is a list in the format above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Just a couple of parts in the wrong order

```
[[s, c] for s, c in this_amino if s == min_score]
```

Comment: You're recreating the sublist each time. That feels icky! Still, +1

Comment: Sometimes we need to remember that readability counts too - even if it feels icky.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L = [['0.0', 'AAA'], ['0.0', 'AAC'], ['0.2', 'BBB']]
>>> [subl for subl in L if subl[0] == 0.0]
[]
>>> [subl for subl in L if subl[0] == '0.0']
[['0.0', 'AAA'], ['0.0', 'AAC']]
```

If your list is sorted based on index-0, and the index-0 of the first sublist is `min_score`, then [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) FTW!

```
>>> min_score = '0.0'
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda subl:subl[0]==min_score, L))
[['0.0', 'AAA'], ['0.0', 'AAC']]
```